# Writing a C++11 thread based module for apache

Tags: c++, linux, apache, http, c++11

I'd like to write a module for Apache in C++11 (GCC 4.7) and configure it such that:

- A custom initialization function in my code is called once at server startup.
- Request Handling Workers are spawned by apache as pthreads all in the same process. (Not forking processes)
- HTTP Requests are handled by a function call from the worker threads that call a blocking function I've written in my code.

Is all of this possible?  Or is Apache not designed this way?  If it is possible what is a sketch of how to configure it and to build and attach the module?

Answer (score 1):

It's a long time since I've written Apache modules, but I don't think a module can control whether children are spawned as new forks or processes, I think it's a server-wide setting.

Otherwise, it's all very possible. Apache provides hooks that you can use to call your module's code at various times during the server's runtime.

Back in the Apache 1.3.x days I used to use the book [Writing Apache Modules with Perl and C](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565925670.do) which is mostly focused on using Perl, but has enough info on the C API to figure it out.  The [developer docs for Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/) show how to use the hooks and control request processing.

Comment: I've got most of it working.  I've concluded that using the MPM worker module, it is possible in theory to configure it so it uses a single child process with multiple threads.  Haven't tested this yet though.